# How to start Play application without SBT plugin?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

#### Context.

I'm looking for a way to start a Play application from within a command line tool. This needs to be dependent on the task that needs to be performed, namely an OAuth authorisation.
When the users selects the task, the tool should spawn a browser window that completes the user authentication. When this completes, the rest of the authorisation process continues in the Play app. Once the security token is obtained, the Play app needs to shut down.

#### Question.

Is there a simple way to start (and shutdown) a Play application without using the SBT plugin (provided by Typesafe)?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to start a Play app from anywhere in the code, as simple as listening on a socket -- in a line of code.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [ProductionDist](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionDist):

In SBT run task `dist` (or from CLI `activator dist` or `sbt dist`). It will create a ZIP containing your application and its dependencies, plus a run script in a `bin/' sub-directory.

From directory created by extracting the ZIP content, you can so run the application executing the provided script: `./bin/my-app` (assuming your application is named "my-app").

It will also create a file named `RUNNING_PID` containing the PID (process ID) of the JVM running your application, so that if in background (dettached from the CLI) you can kill it properly:

```
kill `cat /path/to/RUNNING_PID`
```

Comment: While I appreciate this workaround, it still involves using the SBT plugin. I'm looking for a way to start a Play app from anywhere in the code, as simple as listening on a socket -- in a line of code.

Comment: No, it only uses SBT to build the dist, which then is standalone.